# How to loop over an object which contains objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I have an object (lets call it posts) that looks like this

```
[ { _id: 5cc2d552939a9b290bfaee18,
    rating: 1,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5cc2d6362c9b3729253d14eb,
    rating: 4,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

The size of this object changes.

Every time the function is called, I want to loop over posts, and sum the rating. I want to then divide the rating by the number of items in posts.

I've tried to do something like this

```
Object.keys(posts).forEach(function (item, value) {

        });
```

But couldn't manage to get the actual data

Thanks

Comment: that is an array, not an object, make use of Array.map

Comment: Use `Object.entries` or `Object.values` maybe (if it would be an object),  `.forEach`s second argument is an `index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have an object (lets call it posts)*. Let's call it an `array` or a `map`. And you can always loop over the array. You can use simple `for` loop for that.

Looping over will get you the array elements one by one, which would be objects in your case. And now you can easily get the `rating` property value of each object and add them up and then divide by the length of array.

You should end up with something like

```js
var data = [ { _id: '5cc2d552939a9b290bfaee18',
        rating: 1,
        __v: 0 },
      { _id: '5cc2d6362c9b3729253d14eb',
        rating: 4,
        __v: 0 } ];

    var sum = 0;
    
    for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
      sum = sum + data[i].rating;
    }

    var result = sum/data.length;
    
    console.log(result);
```

I explained it all so you don't just copy and paste it. Do read the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> you have an array, not an object. You need to loop over an array, not an
>   object

```
 let posts = [ 
{ _id: 5cc2d552939a9b290bfaee18,rating: 1, __v: 0 },
{ _id: 5cc2d6362c9b3729253d14eb,rating: 4,__v: 0 } 
], sum = 0, average = 0;

//so you need the average of the ratings, get the sum of the ratings

posts.map(post => sum += post.rating);

//divide the sum by the length of the items

average = sum/posts.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh so for starters you looping over an array of just the keys `Object.keys` get's you the keys and not the values so that's useless.

```
    function getAverageRating(posts, detailed)
    {
        let totalPosts = 0;
        let totalRatings = 0;
        posts.forEach(function (item, index) {
            totalRatings += item.rating;
            totalPosts++;
        });
        if(detailed){
            return {"total_posts":totalPosts, "sum_ratings":totaltotalRatings, "avg":totaltotalRatings/totalPosts}
        }else{
            return totaltotalRatings/totalPosts
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an array, the alternatif way is to use `reduce`

```js
const items = [ { _id: '5cc2d552939a9b290bfaee18',
    rating: 1,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: '5cc2d6362c9b3729253d14eb',
    rating: 4,
    __v: 0 } ];
    

// make sure to calculate when there are items
if (items.length) {
  const sumRating = items.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.rating, 0);

  const average = sumRating / items.length;

  console.log(average);
}
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce